# Why does Snowflake exclude matching NULL values in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have a table called `people` where one of the values in the Name column is `null`:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mary |
| 3 | `null` |

I want to select all rows where Name is not equal to "John", so I do:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE Name <> 'John'
```

In Snowflake, this returns **only** "Mary" and **excludes**  the last row with a `null` value for Name. If I want to include `null` values (expected behavior), I have to do:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE (Name <> 'John' OR Name is NULL)
```

Is this expected behavior? And does anyone know how to configure Snowflake to return NULL rows as well?

Since by definition, the absence of a value (i.e. NULL) should match the condition `Name <> 'John'`

Comment: That is how NULL comparisons are defined in SQL.  All databases behave the same way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But for some reason [documentation says](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/where.html) *in  most contexts*, not all or some list of restrictions, which may be really confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All databases handle `NULL`s the same way (well, pretty much so).  Almost any comparison involving `NULL` -- with the notable exceptions of `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` and a few others -- returns `NULL`.  `WHERE` clauses and `CASE` expressions treat `NULL` values the same as "false".

Fortunately, Snowflake also implements the standard SQL `NULL`-safe operator, `IS DISTINCT FROM`.  So you can write the logic as:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
WHERE Name IS DISTINCT FROM 'John'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is common database expected behaviour when every comparison with null returns false.

In other words:

```
if some_variable = null -- always false even if some_variable was assigned null
if some_variable <> null -- always false
```

It is because "null" means "nothing" and it is hard to compare nothing to nothing.

As I can see from the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html) you can avoid writing "or name is null" by using NVL function which takes 2 parameters and returns second parameter if first one is null.

For example:

```
nvl(1, 3) = 1
nvl(null, 3) = 3
```

So your query might be looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE nvl(Name,'John') <> 'John';
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake created [`EQUAL_NULL()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null) which makes NULL handling a lot easier. From docs:

> Compares whether two expressions are equal. The function is NULL-safe,
> meaning it treats NULLs as known values for comparing equality. Note
> that this is different from the EQUAL comparison operator (=), which
> treats NULLs as unknown values.

To negate it use `NOT()` around it.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE NOT(EQUAL_NULL(Name,'John'))
```